# Possible Troll?

Tags: discussion

The user "[Bill](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/users/27765/bill)" here just posted a [(closable as off-topic) question](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/34948/why-dont-companies-seem-to-realize-how-arrogant-they-sound-and-how-angry-the-wo) identical to a [(closed as off-topic) question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/523534/why-dont-companies-seem-to-realize-how-arrogant-they-sound-and-how-angry-the-wo) posted in [ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com) by the user "[Nelson](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/372876/nelson)".